# data.table loop over column names

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, data.table

I have a big data.table with hundreds of columns. Those columns are named `V1, V2, ..., V100` for example.  Somewhere in a `for` loop, I need to assign the values of a column to its preceding one, like this:

```
N = 10
dt <- data.table( V1=rnorm(N), V2=rnorm(N), V3=rnorm(N))
col1 <- str_c("V",1)
col2 <- str_c("V",2) 
dt[, (col2) := if_else( get(col1) > 0, 1, 0 ) ]
```

Thus, it works whenever I change the number `1` and `2` to `j` and `j+1` in a loop. However, it's shown to be slow. I wonder if there is more efficient way to do this? Thanks

Comment: You had better to avoid loop if possible. Show your code of loop in your question and we can help you improve that.

Comment: The loop you said in context is not clear for me. I don't know the range of `j`. `for(j=?:?)`

Comment: Don't forget to use `set.seed()` function

Comment: Which one is your loop order? `V1 V2 -> V2 V3` or `V1 V2 -> V3 V4`?

Comment: In addition to the `set.seed`, lack of `for` loop, and clarity on the columns ... if you're using `data.table`, then use `fifelse` instead of `if_else`. They are functionally equivalent (and share the same improvements over `base::ifelse`), but I'd think a `data.table`-based solution should stick to functions not within `dplyr` (unless you explicitly need them).

Comment: While I don't completely understand what you're trying to accomplish (since your code doesn't quite match your description), `data.table::set` is a low-overhead way of updating columns (or subsets of columns) designed specifically for use in loops.